# Google Sheets - Join unique cells in a row

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, unique

I am trying to get only unique values while using the function

=JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(FILTER(D$1:D$230,E$1:E$230=G1)))

It is working, except that some of the values it is grabbing are arrays themselves, so from one of my filter's data sets:

22; 14, 21; 15; 6; 19; 1, 13; 1; 19; 14 (each set between colons are on a separate row)

using the join function mentioned above, I end up with a cell with the values (lets call it value-set Alpha):

{22, {14, 21}, 15, 6, 19, {1, 13}, 1, 14}
(it's not written as such, but I know that is how it is handling it)

As you can tell, it is preventing the second 19 from appearing as it is no longer unique, but I am unable to break down the array of {14, 21} to prevent 14 from appearing twice. I thought I could use the function =split(I1,",") on the value set Alpha above, which split every number up into it's own cell and then join it back displaying only the unique sets, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to join it together without including duplicates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show few sample data then expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(FILTER(D1:D230,E1:E230=G1),","))),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))))`

If, in fact, your Col-D and Col-E ranges run the full column, top to bottom, you can shorten things a bit:

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(FILTER(D:D,E:E=G1),","))),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))))`

In any case, you see the `FILTER` at center.

`SPLIT` splits at any commas.

`TRIM` removes any leading spaces the result as of that `SPLIT`.

`FLATTEN` forms one column of all results. Understand that it will flatten the entire virtual grid, which will be as many columns wide as the largest number of comma-separated elements in any cell from the Col-D range. If your max elements was two, then the virtual grid formed by `SPLIT` will be two columns wide — with most of the rightmost cells blank. So when you `FLATTEN`, those blanks will still be interposed into the list. (See below.)

`QUERY` removes the blanks as described above, tightening the list to a contiguous vertical array of remaining non-null values.

`UNIQUE` weeds out duplicates.

Finally, `JOIN` joins with comma-space.